# background-color on inline elements without inline padding

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the background-color to wrap exactly around the inline characters.

Can't explain it any better so here's an image showing exactly what I want:

[image: desired effect]

HTML

```
<div>
  <span>HTML Text block - HTML Text block</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  max-width: 300px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

span {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 black;
  padding: 0;
}
```

If it can't be done with CSS alone, can JavaScript be of any help?

[Here's a codepen](http://codepen.io/dcrck/pen/vOXrmQ)

Comment: This would only work if the glyphs in the font all had the exact same metrics, e.g. if every capital letter was of the exact same width and height, or if every symbol's edges touched the glyph edges, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Layout Experiments</title>
  <style>
    *{
      -webkit-box-sizing :border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing    :border-box;
      box-sizing         :border-box;
    }
    div{
      max-width      :300px;
      line-height    :1.5;
      text-transform :uppercase;
      height         :200px;
      background     :wheat;
    }
    span{
      background-color :white;
      box-shadow       :5px 5px 0 black;
      padding          :0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <span>HTML Text block - HTML Text block HTML Text block - HTML Text block</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:`<span>`HTML Text`<br>` block -`<br>` HTML Text`<br>` block`</span>`